# Is Legilimency similar to Divination?

Tags: harry-potter

I know one is deja vu and one is telepathy, but in psychic awareness in the Harry Potter world are they similar?

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Legilimency / https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Divination

Answer (score 7):

## No, Legilimency and Divination aren’t alike.

Legilimency and Divination are quite different subjects - Legilimency allows insight into others’ minds, Divination is meant to predict the future. There’s no overlap between the two.

### Legilimency allows insight into others’ minds.

Legilimency is a way of seeing into others’ thoughts, which can be used to find out if they’re telling the truth. A Legilimens could tell if someone’s lying, and may know other details about what they’re thinking.

> “Only Muggles talk of “mind-reading”. The mind is not a book, to be opened at will and examined at leisure. Thoughts are not etched on the inside of skulls, to be perused by any invader. The mind is a complex and many-layered thing, Potter – or at least, most minds are.’ He smirked. ‘It is true, however, that those who have mastered Legilimency are able, under certain conditions, to delve into the minds of their victims and to interpret their findings correctly. The Dark Lord, for instance, almost always knows when somebody is lying to him. Only those skilled at Occlumency are able to shut down those feelings and memories that contradict the lie, and so can utter falsehoods in his presence without detection.’
>
> Whatever Snape said, Legilimency sounded like mind-reading to Harry, and he didn’t like the sound of it at all.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24 (Occlumency)*</sup></sub>

However, Legilimency is not a way of predicting future events. A Legilimens would not be able to tell what will happen in the future. They only can tell what others are thinking.

### Divination is intended to predict the future.

Divination, whichever of the several known methods are used, is intended to predict the future.

> “Many witches and wizards, talented though they are in the area of loud bangs and smells and sudden disappearings, are yet unable to penetrate the veiled mysteries of the future,’ Professor Trelawney went on, her enormous, gleaming eyes moving from face to nervous face. ‘It is a Gift granted to few.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 6 (Talons and Tea Leaves)*</sup></sub>

Divination cannot, and is never said to be able to, divine what others are thinking or feeling. It’s a subject that encompasses several different ways of attempting to predict the future.

Answer (score 3):

## They are vaguely similar, but not the same.

---

### Divination is sort of like seeing the future.

During Harry's first Divination class with Professor Trelawney, she mentions that Divination is an art which reveals aspects of the future: (emphasis mine)

> "Many witches and wizards, talented though they are in the area of loud bangs and smells and sudden disappearings, are yet unable to **penetrate the veiled mysteries of the future**," Professor Trelawney [said].
>   
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban | Chapter 6*</sup></sub>

### Legilimency is sort of like mind-reading.

When Harry has Occlumency lessons with Professor Snape, the latter initially, like Trelawney, talks about what Legilimency is. He describes it as reading minds, though refuses to acknowledge that term: (emphasis mine)

> "It is true, however, that those who have mastered Legilimency are able, under certain conditions, to delve into the minds of their victims and to interpret their findings correctly. The Dark Lord, for instance, almost always knows when somebody is lying to him. Only those skilled at Occlumency are able to shut down those feelings and memories that contradict the lie, and so can utter falsehoods in his presence without detection."
>
> Whatever Snape said, **Legilimency sounded like mind-reading** to Harry, and he didn’t like the sound of it at all.
>   
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix | Chapter 24*</sup></sub>

### So...

Really, they both read deeper into one thing or the other using magic. However, Divination reads into the future, while Legilimency looks inside another's brain. Another difference is the fact that any witch or wizard skilled at Divination may look into the future without being blocked. Legilimency, on the other hand, can be stopped by someone who is a skilled Occlumens.